# Servlet session issue

Tags: servlets

I am facing an issue with servlet URL rewriting.

My LogoutServlet doPost() method code is:

```
//invalidate the session if exists
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null) session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("login.html");
```

My Checkout.jsp code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%
if(request.getSession(false) == null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
}
%>
<h3>Hi there, do the checkout.</h3>
<br>
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch it, after login page, I see URL like

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/CheckoutPage.jsp;jsessionid=XYZ
```

When I click on logout button, it forwards me to the login page.

The issue is that if I provide URL as above with jsessionid, then it doesn't forward me to login page and shows the JSP data.

I am not sure how JSP is getting the session as its invalidated in Logout servlet.

Comment: The issue was that the action in form is not encoded, so LogoutServlet doesn't get session info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session is created by default as soon as a JSP is being executed. You shouldn't use the existence of a session to determine if a user is logged in or not. Instead, you should store some flag or object in the session to mark it as an authenticated session, after a successful login.

If the flag is or object is in the session (or is true), then the user is authenticated. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: Ok, I changed my Login servlet code to add a session attribute with name "user" and changed Checkout.jsp condition to: if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("user") == null){
 response.sendRedirect("login.html");
} but even this is not working.

Comment: I copied the URL with jsessionid and then clicked on Logout button that will invalidate the session. Then I pasted the URL in browser and I get the JSP page rather than getting forwarded to login.html page.

Comment: When you talk about URL rewriting, do you mean you deactivated cookies? Is there a session in the LogoutServlet?

Comment: Yes I have deactivated the cookie, did some debugging and found that in LogoutServlet request.getSession(false) is returning NULL. So how do I get the session and invalidate it?

Comment: That means that the link pointing to the servlet hasn't been properly encoded, and doesn't contain the jsessionid. Without this, since you disabled cookies, the server can't know which session to attach the request to. The code should be `<form action="<c:url value='LogoutServlet'/>" method="post">`. The JSTL `<c:url>` tag properly encodes the URL.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue. Figured out just before your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The invalidate method just in validates the method. It does not set it to null. You can check for any attribute stored in the session to check weather it is null or not.

Comment: so how can I make sure that if I try to access the JSP directly with jsessionid, it forwards it to login page?

Comment: As I said you must be storing some attribute in the session. So in you check that attribute, then it will be null and if it is null you can forward the user to the login page.